# Edit rectangle boxes in PDF with Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

is it possible to edit an exsisting PDF content with Java? I'm trying out iText but I dont find any clue on how to move objects or change their z-Pos.

Case: I have crop-marks on a exsisting PDF. We add stamper with iText but they are on top position (z-index). Now we need to access the cropmark rectangles and put them on the top layer position.

How is that possible?

Best
Marcel

Comment: What you want to do is difficult in general. If your PDFs are somewhat uniform in their inner build, please supply samples, maybe there is an easy way for that special case.

Comment: Hi mkl, our PDFs are generated by a FOP-engine and therefore should be very uniform. How would you look into the PDF? I cant provide a sample right now, since these PDFs include customer details

Comment: You can look into them using PDF object model browsers like RUPS. You should know the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) quite well, though. Otherwise you'll understand nothing or (maybe even worse) jump to false conclusions.

Comment: Thanks, I could figure it out using the offical Acrobat API for C++ which also has a java interface. I think it is the best way to archive my goal